# full duplex Tcp data exchange c#

Tags: c#, networkstream

I have a full duplex connection between two hosts that exchange datas with a thread that always listen on NetworkStream.Read(). How can I close gracefully the connection avoiding:

1- the deadlock of the two side read() function

2- the abort() of reading threads [closing they safely]

I think closing the connection with SocketShutdown.Send but how it works? It unlock the Read() on the other side.. There are not many things in the documentation.

Thak you

Comment: IMHO, one of the best places to start learning sockets is here: http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/ The MSDN documentation also has the information you seek, if you're patient. I admit the code examples there aren't the best, but they do generally work and illustrate how to write some kinds of network code. Long ago, I wrote an article intended to introduce basic networking techniques to .NET programmers: http://blogs.msmvps.com/duniho/2008/08/19/basic-network-programming-in-net/ Maybe you'll find it a more useful example than those on MSDN.

Answer (score 4):

A simple network exchange looks something like this:

```
Server: create socket
Server: listen on socket
Client: create socket
Client: connect to server's address
Server: accept connection, which returns a new socket to use for that connection
Client: receive new socket from result of connect operation
```

Now the connection is established. There will be some defined protocol for communicating with each other. That protocol will dictate who starts. It can be either, but for this example, let's assuming it's the client:

```
Client: send some data
Server: receive the data
Server: send a response
Client: receive the data
Client: shutdown with "send" (but still be prepared to receive)
Server: receive completes with 0 (indicates no more data will be sent by client)
Server: shutdown with "both"
Client: receive completes with 0 (indicates no more data will be sent by server)
Server & Client: close sockets
```

Answering your specific questions:

1. `How is deadlock avoided?` There's no deadlock potential here. Servers and clients both are often written using asynchronous networking APIs. But if the defined protocol is a straightforward request/response protocol (e.g. HTTP), even that's not strictly required. Each end can be single-threaded, alternating between sending and receiving as appropriate for the protocol.
2. 'How do you abort the reading threads?` You don't. If you are indeed dedicating a whole thread to reading from the socket (and that's really not very good design), then the thread simply exits when it sees a receive operation complete with 0 bytes as the length.

Comment: why "that's really not very good design"? Is better to use callbackfunction?

Comment: Yes, either that or the new `async/await` pattern. There are several different mechanisms supported in .NET for asynchronous handling of I/O in general, and for sockets specifically. Correct use of those APIs ensures efficient use of resources, while dedicating a whole thread to a single operation does not.